# Merging almost unique rows together

Tags: sql-server

I have this table

[image]

And i need have this (In source table are thousands values)

[image]

How can i do that ?

Here is example database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4278d

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if the first row also has a value in variable2? Also I assume [this is the SQLfiddle you wanted (with different name/column2 values)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4278d).

Comment: There aro no rows with more then one Variable defined in one row. That situation happened me from pivoting multiple columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that each row in the source table only has either variable1, 2 or 3 populated, and there is only one such row for each combination, then this is probably the simplest approach:

```
SELECT Name, Column2, 
  MAX(Variable1),
  MAX(Variable2),
  MAX(Variable3)
FROM dbo.DataTable
GROUP BY Name, Column2;
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4278d/1)

Comment: Thank you, i did not realize that i can use GROUP function :-)